# cllocation to UIWebView - iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, cllocation

I am wondering if there is away to send the lat and long of a person's location to a URL? It would also need to have their UDID number to match with the database.

Here is what I have so far:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {    
     NSString *query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                          @"http://example.com/ihome.php?uid=%@", 
                          [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier], 
                          @"&year=2010%@"];
     NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:query];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [ NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url ];
     webView.opaque = NO;
     webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     [webView loadRequest: requestObj ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to calculate the longitude and the latitude before to request the URL.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self; // send location updates to this object
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
     NSLog(@"Your location: %@", [newLocation description]);

     NSString *query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                          @"http://mysite.com/ihome.php?uid=%@&longitude=%d&latitude=%d", 
                          [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier], 
                          @"&year=2010%@",
                          newLocation.longitude,
                          newLocation.latitude];
     NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:query];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [ NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url ];
     webView.opaque = NO;
     webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     [webView loadRequest: requestObj ];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}
```

Comment: I get errors saying /Users/russellharrower/Documents/iPhone/QH/WebViewController.m:18:0 /Users/russellharrower/Documents/iPhone/QH/WebViewController.m:18: error: request for member 'locationManager' in something not a structure or union

and fours other errors

In my .h file I have this
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController {
 IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;


@end

Have I missed something? My m file has the above code you added.

Comment: Now I only have two errors - 
error: request for member 'longitude' in something not a structure or union

error: request for member 'latitude' in something not a structure or union

Comment: Ah sorry, I have made a mistake. Before the NSString *query, use it:
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
 if (!location) {
  return;
 }
 
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

And then use coordonate.longitude and coordonate.latitude instead of the newLocation.longitude or latitude.